# Download speed is significantly slower on windows xp - httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest

I am downloading large file located on one drive servers.

usually on windows 7 > the download speed reaches 1500kb/s max.

On windows xp the download reaches 500kb/s max.

What could possibly be the cause of this?

```
  private void DownloadFileRange(string sSourceURL, string sDestinationPath)
    {
        long iFileSize = 0;
        int iBufferSize = 8192;
        long tamanioArchivoExistente = 0;
        System.IO.FileStream saveFileStream;
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwRq;
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse hwRes;
        try
        {

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(sDestinationPath))
            {
                System.IO.FileInfo fINfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(sDestinationPath);
                tamanioArchivoExistente = fINfo.Length;

            }
            if (tamanioArchivoExistente > 0)
                saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(sDestinationPath, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
            else
                saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(sDestinationPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);



            hwRq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sSourceURL);
            hwRq.Proxy = null;

            //Esto funciona con NET 3.5
            if (tamanioArchivoExistente > 0)
            {

                hwRq.AddRange(tamanioArchivoExistente);
            }

            hwRes = (HttpWebResponse)hwRq.GetResponse();
            iFileSize = hwRes.ContentLength + tamanioArchivoExistente;

            System.IO.Stream smRespStream;
            smRespStream = hwRes.GetResponseStream();

            if (tamanioArchivoExistente > 0)
            {
                bytesDescargados = tamanioArchivoExistente;
            }

            int iByteSize;
            byte[] downBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize];

            while ((iByteSize = smRespStream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the machines have the same hardware?

Comment: I tried in two windows XP PC's, one had 1 Gb RAM and downloaded 350 kb/s and the one with 2 gb RAM downloaded 450 kb/s but I am not sure if it the RAM's fault

Answer (score -1):

Windows XP is nearly 15 years old.  T1's were considered fast then, at 1.5mbps (187kB/s)-- so it would seem likely that the internal TCP stack was optimized for those conditions-- e.g. smaller buffers to help with latency and memory usage.  I would expect it to not handle higher bandwidth as optimally as more modern iterations would.

All that said, your 8K buffer does seem a bit small.  Have you tried increasing `iBufferSize` to something larger, say 262,144 bytes?